# When do I need to create a user pool with AWS?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a mobile app which only uses Facebook for user authentication.There is already a federated user pool. I have created a dataset and now I can send data to the user profile to the Cognito dataset. I want to know

1. Do I still need to create an identity user pool?
2. How can I access user's Facebook data?
3. If I save a data to a dataset can I access it in the dynamoDB? Or how can I access it?
4. Am I missing anything with just using Federated user pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to federate Facebook users into AWS, you can just use Federated Identity Service and you only need a **federated identity pool**. Any users you federate in using this will have corresponding identity ids. Profile information from Facebook or any other identity provider is not stored with this identity id.

When you use Cognito Sync with federated identity service, data sets are created withing identities and are stored with Cognito and all the data saved in these data sets is with Cognito. DynamoDB only comes into picture here, if you want to create your database on top of Cognito Sync.

Cognito User Pools is acts as your own IDP just like Facebook. If you don't want to use social identity providers and want to create your own you can create a **User Pool** with User Pools service. Users created within this user pool have profile which can be read and updated.

Hope this clarifies the separation between Cognito services.